# How can i create input fields using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm trying to add input fields to a page dynamically, when a user clicks a button.

I have the following code, which is being called, but doesn't work as expected

```
var a= document.getElementsByTagName("button");
a[0].addEventListener("click", clicked);
function clicked(){
  var input = document.createElement("input");
  document.appendChild("input");
}
```

The error I am facing is this:

```
"error"
"TypeError: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.
    at HTMLButtonElement.clicked (sofodipabe.js:5:12)"
```

What is causing this issue?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Same way you create any other element with javascript. It doesn't appear that any research effort has been done before asking here. Please take some time to read [ask] and [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users?s=1|2.0169)

Answer (score 1):

Do you wish to use jQuery? If you are using jQuery you can follow my easy solution below other wise @kira-sen had provided good solution.

Here is the [fiddle you may look at](https://jsfiddle.net/animeshsinghweb/v7j5m8j3/1/).

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" id="n" placeholder="How may elements to add">
<button id="addElements">Add elements</button> <br>
<div id="addElementsHere">

</div>
```

**JS**

```
$("#addElements").click(function(e){
    var n = parseInt($(this).siblings("#n").val());

  for(var i = 0; i<n; i++){
        $("#addElementsHere").append("<input class='xyz' type='text' placeholder=' Enter value for input number " + (i + 1) + "' id='inp-"+(i+1)+"'>");
  }

});
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this as an example to do what you want.

```js
var container = document.querySelector('#container')

for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  var input = document.createElement('input') // create a new element
  input.classList.add('input') // Add .input class to the created element
  input.placeholder = 'Input ' + i // set an attribute
  input.id = 'input' + i // set the ID
  container.append(input) // Append the element to a parent element (container in this case)
}
```

```css
.input {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```js
// Creating 10 Input textboxes
var div = document.createElement('div');

for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  var inputElement=document.createElement('input');
  inputElement.setAttribute('type','text');
  inputElement.setAttribute('id','id' + i);
  inputElement.value='My Value ' + (i+1);
  div.appendChild(inputElement);
}

document.getElementById("container").appendChild(div);

// Adding class
var inputElements = document.querySelectorAll('input');

for(var i=0; i < inputElements.length; i++) {
  inputElements[i].className='MyClass' + i;
  // Getting value
  console.log(inputElements[i].value);
}
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
```